# WordPress Как добавить термины к посту через код

Tags: php, wordpress

в родительской теме есть функция которая регистрирует таксономию (тип курсов):

```
add_action( 'init', 'createTaxonomy', 99999 );
function createTaxonomy() {
$course_type = array(
    'label' => 'Тип курса',
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'public' => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_tagcloud' => true,
    'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
    'query_var' => true,
);

register_taxonomy('course_type', array('stm-courses'), $course_type); // category
}
```

Мне нужно добавить метки по умолчанию в дочерней теме (можно и в родительской), чтобы в админке было, допустим, курс обычный, курс профессиональный и т.д. Чтобы это было реализовано через код, а не вручную. Как это можно реализовать?

[image: Тут добавить метки]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы добавить термин к посту используйте `wp_set_object_terms`:

```
wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $terms, $taxonomy );
```

Comment: Спасибо! В родительской теме добавляю:
    $post_id = get_the_ID();
    wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, 'simple', 'course_type', array('stm-courses'));  Но метка не добавляется. Можете подсказать как сделать? Можно даже на примере основной функции регистрации таксономии

Comment: @4efirrr `$terms` должен быть строкой или массивом, а вы передаете 2 строки. Сделайте массивом и будет работать.

Comment: @Neolot добавляю: $post_type = get_post_type('stm-courses');
wp_set_object_terms( $post_type, array('simple'), 'course_type');

Всё равно не работает

Comment: @4efirrr Первый параметр должен быть `$post_id`, а вы что передаете? Будьте внимательнее.

Comment: @Neolot делал и $post_id и get_post() и get_the_ID() результат нулевой

Comment: @4efirrr пришлите что вы передаете в ф-цию

Comment: @Krya например: wp_set_object_terms( get_the_ID(), array('test1', 'test2'),'course_type')